# Generic method passing parameters - java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap

Tags: java, json, generics, gson

I have a simple generic class:

```
public class OwnedCollection<T extends BaseObject> extends BaseObject {

    private String playerId;
    private List<T> collection;


public OwnedCollection(String playerId, List<T> collection) {
    super(playerId);
    this.playerId = playerId;
    this.collection = collection;
}
```

}

I want to deserialize it from json. I am using Gson library, so
When i call the line:

```
OwnedCollection<Skin> fromJson = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<OwnedCollection<Skin>>() {}.getType());
```

everything is working fine.

But when i try to create a method for doing this i get exceptions.
I have tried the following:

```
public <T extends BaseObject> OwnedCollection<T> deserialize1(String json, Class<T> type) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<T>() {
    }.getType());
}
```

and calling it with:

```
OwnedCollection<Skin> deserialize1 = deserialize1(json, Skin.class);
```

i get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.miracledojo.karatedo.domen.item.Skin cannot be cast to org.miracledojo.karatedo.domen.item.OwnedCollection
```

then:

```
public <T extends BaseObject> OwnedCollection<T> deserialize2(String json, Type type) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

and calling it with:

```
deserialize2(json, Skin.class);
```

then i get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.miracledojo.karatedo.domen.item.Skin cannot be cast to org.miracledojo.karatedo.domen.item.OwnedCollection
```

Does anybody have any ideas?
Something like:

```
OwnedCollection<Skin>.class
```

is not possible, so any similar sintax?

Comment: Looks like you should use `new TypeToken<OwnedCollection<T>>` in your `deserialize1` method instead of `new TypeToken<T>`

Comment: @IvanPronin I am able to serialize it that way but not in the appropriate object. When i try to call some method in generic class, i am also getting java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to org.miracledojo.karatedo.domen.BaseObject

Answer (score 1):

You are giving the GSON parser the incorrect type token, change the type token to be an OwnedCollection of type T

```
public <T extends BaseObject> OwnedCollection<T> deserialize1(String json, Class<T> type) {
    return new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<OwnedCollection<T>>(){}.getType());
}
```

Comment: I am able to serialize it that way but not in the appropriate object. When i try to call some method in generic class, i am also getting java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to org.miracledojo.karatedo.domen.BaseObject